# Update count in php

Tags: php, sql-update

I'm working on a project in which you select how many items you want. My goal is to update this number of rows in my database.

For instance, if someone selects 2 iphones, I want to select the two first iphones of my database where the status is `available` and switch it to `taken`.

Do you have any idea how I can do this in php? I tried update count, it didn't work.

Comment: Could you provide your existing code to your question, so that we may see what your attempts have been, as well as being able to have an idea of your application? At the moment, we have very little information to go by. It's rather difficult to add functionality to something you can't see for yourself.

Comment: Nevermind, I tried to do "UPDATE COUNT" when I really needed to do update table set statut='taken' limit 2. I'm going to provide the answer.

Comment: Your table doesn't sound like a good structure. Id have a row for each model and have a count for them.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, The proper way to do it is to add a limit. In my case :

```
$requete=$pdo->query(" UPDATE iphone SET iphoneStatus='taken' limit 2");
```

Comment: You should use a `where` clause so you only the update the records you want updated.